# How display result count from query

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

I'm working on a RESTful API project, and I have problem that my code can query with gorm, my query like this `countSequenceId := db.Debug().Raw("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM SMSBlast2").Scan(&smsblast1)`. I have the result `[1 rows affected or returned]`, that mean success to count my all row in database , but I want to display the result like `result count = 10`, but how?

[image]

```
 package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mssql"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

type SMSBlast struct {
    SequenceID   int `gorm:"primary_key";column:"SequenceID"`
    MobilePhone string `gorm:"column:MobilePhone"`
    Output  string  `gorm:"column:Output"`
    WillBeSentDate *time.Time `gorm:"column:WillBeSentDate"`
    SentDate *time.Time `gorm:"column:SentDate"`
    Status *string `gorm:"column:Status"`
    DtmUpd time.Time `gorm:"column:DtmUpd"`
}

func (SMSBlast) TableName() string {
    return "SMSBlast2"
}

func allSMSBlasts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    db, err := gorm.Open("mssql", "sqlserver://sa:@localhost:1433?database=CONFINS")
    if err != nil{
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    defer db.Close()

    var smsblasts []SMSBlast
    db.Debug().Find(&smsblasts)
    fmt.Println("{}",smsblasts)

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(smsblasts)
}

func insertSMSBlast(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Println("New Insert Created")

    db, err := gorm.Open("mssql", "sqlserver://sa:@localhost:1433?database=CONFINS")
    if err != nil{
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    defer db.Close()

    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    mobilephone := vars["mobilephone"]
    output := vars["output"]

    var(
        smsblast1 SMSBlast
    )


    countSequenceId := db.Debug().Raw("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM SMSBlast2").Scan(&smsblast1)
    fmt.Println(countSequenceId)


    msg, err :=  json.Marshal(countSequenceId)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }



    sequenceid1,_ := strconv.Atoi(string(msg))
    fmt.Println("SequenceID : " , sequenceid1)

    smsblasts := SMSBlast{SequenceID: sequenceid1,MobilePhone: mobilephone,Output:output, DtmUpd: time.Now()}
    prindata := db.Create(&smsblasts)
    fmt.Println(prindata)

func handleRequests(){
    myRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/smsblaststest",allSMSBlasts).Methods("POST")
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/smsblaststestInsert/{mobilephone}/{output}", insertSMSBlast).Methods("POST")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080",myRouter))

}

func main(){
    fmt.Println("SMSBLASTS ORM")
    handleRequests()
}
```

Comment: If you look at the docs for gorm's [DB](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm) you'll see that almost all of its methods return the `*DB` instance itself, this includes [`Scan`](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.Scan) and [`Count`](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.Count) and that means that `countSequenceId` is neither an *id*, nor *count*.

Comment: You can try `x := db.Find(&smsblasts)` `fmt.Println(x.RowsAffected)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using the Raw method for this, but I'd like to point out there's a Count method to achieve what you want: http://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Count

```
db.Where("name = ?", "jinzhu").Or("name = ?", "jinzhu 2").Find(&users).Count(&count)
//// SELECT * from USERS WHERE name = 'jinzhu' OR name = 'jinzhu 2'; (users)
//// SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE name = 'jinzhu' OR name = 'jinzhu 2'; (count)

db.Model(&User{}).Where("name = ?", "jinzhu").Count(&count)
//// SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE name = 'jinzhu'; (count)
```

I put together a very simple example from the docs:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
)

type Porg struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", "test.db")
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Migrate the schema
    db.AutoMigrate(&Porg{})

    // Create
    for i := 1; i <= 100; i++ {
        db.Create(&Porg{Name: "John"})
    }

    // Read
    var porgs []Porg
    var count int
    db.Model(&porgs).Count(&count)

    fmt.Println(count)
}
```

Output: 100

Using the `Model` method you can Specify a model to query, this won't query the DB directly. Using `db.Find(&porgs).Count(&count)` will actually send 2 SQL queries to the db.

Comment: I want count my row, not looping, I want to extract [1 rows affected or returned] to display count

Comment: The `[1 rows affected or returned` message comes from the Debug() method, it just allows you to debug problems quicker. `Count` isn't looping through the results, it's sending a `SELECT COUNT(*) Table` query to your database.

Comment: I've updated the example, using `Model().Count()` you're able to send just a single SQL query to the database, instead of 2 as when using `Find()`

Comment: How do we check for error at the same time?